# selecting multiple dates in a calendar

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

i need to add checkboxes to every cell in the calendar so that the user can select multiple dates and the dates get stored in the database for later retrieval.
basically i am developing a calendar as a signup sheet for day shift and night shift. so i need 2 checkboxes per calendar date in the calendar. is it possible. i am using Visual studio and c sharp

Comment: Of course it's possible! Is this a web app or a desktop app?

Comment: its a desktop app.. how do i add the checkboxes to the calendar. thats my question

Comment: Let me back up and say "Welcome to StackOverflow!" You'll get much better answers if you show us the code you have so far and what you've tried to do that didn't work. Are you using an existing calendar control or rolling your own? Is it WinForms or WPF?

Comment: its just a normal winform calendar. i want to add 2 checkboxes per date. how do i do it. i have not written any code yet. just in the design phase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your question whether or not this is possible?  Then the answer is "Yes!"  --  What else would you like to know?  Are there any details to your question?  Specific areas you would like to concentrate on?  Areas that are causing you problems?  Or are you simply looking for a full solution?

Comment: This isn't really an answer... (admittedly, to something that isn't really a question)

Comment: how do i do it? i know it can be done. but i dont know how?

Comment: Why don't you get us started.  Tell us what you think is the way to get this done, and we'll help you with some of the details

Comment: thanks for your help..
i am new to visual studio and hence i dont know how to do it.
i just wanted to know how to add checkboxes to a calendar control.
never mind